# Websocket with special characters

Tags: node.js, go, websocket, tcp

I am using websocket with client nodejs and server golang (net library) via tcp. I am read data sent from client but many special chars. Some one can help me about that?

Data received:

\u0016\u0003\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\ufffd\u0003\u0003x\ufffd_\ufffdj\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdȬ{\ufffd \ufffdI\u003c9\u000bC1YŲ\ufffdVp\u0017\ufffd\u000e`\ufffd \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0017\ufffd\ufffd=\\u0002\ufffd~,\u0011\ufffdn\ufffd\ufffdY\u0010\ufffd\u001c\ufffdw\u000f\ufffd\ufffd(hfK\ufffd\ufffd\u0000 \u001a\u001a\u0013\u0001\u0013\u0002\u0013\u0003\ufffd+\ufffd/\ufffd,\ufffd0̨̩\ufffd\u0013\ufffd\u0014\u0000\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\u0000/\u00005\u0001\u0000\u0001\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0012\u0000\u0000\u000fvenus.localhost\u0000\u0017\u0000\u0000\ufffd\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000"

This func use to accept tcp

```
func (s *WebsocketServer) Serve() {
    if s.running {
        return
    }
    s.running = true

    for _, lsn := range s.lsnList {
        for i := 0; i < s.accepts; i++ {
            go func(lsn2 *net.TCPListener) {
                var (
                    conn *net.TCPConn
                    err  error
                )
                for {
                    if conn, err = AcceptTCP(lsn2); err != nil {
                        // if listener close then return
                        log.Error("listener.Accept(\"%s\") error(%v)", lsn2.Addr().String(), err)
                        return
                    }
                    if err = conn.SetKeepAlive(s.c.Keepalive); err != nil {
                        log.Error("conn.SetKeepAlive() error(%v)", err)
                        return
                    }
                    if err = conn.SetReadBuffer(s.c.ReceiveBuf); err != nil {
                        log.Error("conn.SetReadBuffer() error(%v)", err)
                        return
                    }
                    if err = conn.SetWriteBuffer(s.c.SendBuf); err != nil {
                        log.Error("conn.SetWriteBuffer() error(%v)", err)
                        return
                    }

                    go s.establishWebsocketConnection(conn)
                }
            }(lsn)
        }
    }
}

func (s *WebsocketServer) establishWebsocketConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    var (
        // conn2         = NewBufferedConnSize(conn, 66560)
        req           *websocket.Request
        websocketConn *websocket.Conn
        err           error
    )

    rr := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    if req, err = websocket.ReadRequest(rr); err != nil || req.RequestURI != "/apiws" {
        conn.Close()
        if err != io.EOF {
            log.Errorf("websocket.ReadRequest(rr) error(%v)", err)
        }
        return
    } else {
        wr := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
        websocketConn, err = websocket.Upgrade(conn, rr, wr, req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf("websocket.Upgrade(rr) error(%v)", err)
            conn.Close()
            return
        }
    }

    codec, err := NewCodecByName(s.c.ProtoName, websocketConn)
    tcpConn := NewTcpConnection2(s.c.ServerName, websocketConn, s.c.SendChanSize, codec, true, s)

    // log.Info("establishTcpConnection...")
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            log.Error("tcp_server handle panic: %v\n%s", err, debug.Stack())
            tcpConn.Close()
        }
    }()

    s.onNewConnection(tcpConn)

    for {
        tcpConn.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 6))
        msg, err := tcpConn.Receive()
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("conn: %s recv error: %v", tcpConn, err)
            return
        }

        if msg == nil {
            log.Error("recv a nil msg by conn: %s", tcpConn)
            continue
        }

        if s.callback != nil {
            // log.Info("onConnectionDataArrived - conn: %s", conn)
            if err := s.callback.OnConnectionDataArrived(tcpConn, msg); err != nil {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Function from websocket file, I print data here like above

```
func ReadRequest(r *bufio.Reader) (req *Request, err error) {
    var (
        b  []byte
        ok bool
    )
    req = &Request{reader: r}
    if b, err = req.readLine(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    log.Errorf("websocket.ReadRequest: %s", string(b))

    if req.Method, req.RequestURI, req.Proto, ok = parseRequestLine(string(b)); !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("malformed HTTP request %s", b)
    }
    if req.Header, err = req.readMIMEHeader(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    req.Host = req.Header.Get("Host")
    return req, nil
}

func (r *Request) readLine() ([]byte, error) {
    var line []byte
    for {
        l, more, err := r.reader.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        // Avoid the copy if the first call produced a full line.
        if line == nil && !more {
            return l, nil
        }
        line = append(line, l...)
        if !more {
            break
        }
    }
    return line, nil
}
```

Please help me

Comment: webSocket or plain TCP (you mention both)?  Are you trying to make a webSocket connection to a plain TCP server?  A webSocket client can only successfully connect to a webSocket server as webSocket has it's own connection scheme and data format.

Comment: Can you show the nodejs client-side code so we can see what you're sending and how you're doing that?  Questions here about code generally get faster and more accurate answers if you show the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, I am not sending anything to server. Just connecting to. I am using websocket from lib.webworker.d.ts (I try with w3cwebsocket lib are the same) and server is plain tcp. my url is just http://venus.localhost. connect is not successful. I would like to parse GET /apiws HTTP/1.1 from connection that is connecting.

Comment: Hi all, I have edit my post. I think it helps all comprehend about my problems

Comment: webSocket is a whole protocol and data format.  You can't use a plain TCP server unless you're going to implement the whole webSocket protocol yourself for that server.  It's a pain to implement so I'd recommend using a pre-built webSocket server library for your environment.